# EWS: Stop tracking changes while programmatically editing appointments

Tags: outlook, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I'm editing Outlook appointments programmatically, synchronizing them with "appointments" of another software.

Next time my interface runs and I get the changelog, I don't want to get the changes I made programmatically on an Outlook appointment. Is there a way to stop tracking these changes?

Comment: It all depends on how that other software collects the changes.

Comment: Can you provide more information? Are you making changes with the Outlook object model or EWS? If EWS, what versions of Exchange do you target? Which actors are there, your software, users, other software?

Comment: I'm making changes with EWS and I use Exchange 2010. Actors are my interface and Users who create/edit/delete appointments. I need to get  all user changes with service.SyncFolderItems. But I don't want to track changes my Interface makes on the appointments during runtime. 

Currently I just save the new synchronization state after I did my changes. But is there another way to stop tracking changes?

Answer (score 1):

Have you read the Filtered synchronization section in [Mailbox synchronization and EWS in Exchange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn440952(v=exchg.150).aspx)? I think the only way to ignore the changes your programmatic changes is to do a sync of user changes immediately before running your programmatic changes, then run your program, then do a SyncFolderItems repeatedly and discard the changes (don't do anything with them). That way, the next time you sync changes, you'll only get user created changes that you need to process.